# Check for values in data frame columns, return one.

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a quick and easy task for most of the people here. Though, for me starter in python in gave some problems. Lets say we have:

DATA.

```
g=pd.DataFrame({'AGGRESSION':[0,1,0,0,1], 'DECEPTIVENESS':[0,1,0,0,0]},index=    [1,2,3,4,5])
```

QUESTION AND  DESIRED RESULT. I would like to iterate through rows check for rows where aggresiveness and deceptivness both equal to 1, leave 1 only for deceptivness in the relevant row.

```
g['AGRESSION']=[0,0,0,0,1]
g['DECEPTIVENESS']=[0,1,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.where`:

```
g['AGGRESSION'] = g['AGGRESSION'].where(~((g['AGGRESSION'] == 1) & (g['DECEPTIVENESS'] == 1)), 0)
```

[image]

or Simply:

```
g['AGGRESSION'][(g['AGGRESSION'] == 1) & (g['DECEPTIVENESS'] == 1)] = 0
```